# How to find the stationary probability distribution and determine at what step the probabilities of states will become unchanged

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, linear-algebra

I have the matrix of transition probabilities  and the vector of the initial distribution.

The matrix of transition probabilities:

```
P = [0.35 0.3 0.35; 0.3 0.25 0.45; 0.35 0.3 0.35];
```

The vector of the initial distribution:

```
Vector = [0.1 0.6 0.3];
```

How can I find the stationary probability distribution and determine at what step the probabilities of states will become unchanged?

Comment: Hi, I removed the photo because id adds zero information to the post, as everything in the photo its written in the post. Can you please explain further what you need? We don't even know what fiel dof math or engineering are you talking about

Comment: This is easily solved with [basic algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain). The [`eig`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html) function may be useful